# Established connections is always 1 with DBCP Connection Pooling

Tags: apache-commons-dbcp

I am using apache dbcp with `spring/hibernate/mysql`. Following is the data source bean configuration:

```
<bean id="dbcpDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
        destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://*******"/>
    <property name="username" value="*******"/>
    <property name="password" value="******" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="200" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="50" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000" />
</bean>
```

Somehow on the web server the number, the established connections to mysql server is always less than 2

```
netstat -an | grep  3306 | grep -c ESTABLISHED
```

while the time_wait connections are around 1300-1700

```
netstat -an | grep  3306 | grep -c TIME_WAIT
```

I am expecting the established connections to be atleast 10(since min idle is 10). Am I missing something?